# Is This Code Still a Decorator Pattern Once I Use Lambda's?

Tags: java, lambda, decorator

Is the code below still a Decorator Pattern once I use Lambda's? It doesn't seem to need the 'Concrete' class anymore.

I am trying to learn how to apply lambda's to each example in a Pluralsight Design Pattern class (that was written in Java 7 vs Java 8).

I'd like to know if this method I wrote is what a functional-ish java programmer would use?

```
    /**
     * In this, you only need one interface.  Is it still a decorator pattern?
     * uses Lambda and forEach
     */
    public static void main_three() {

        System.out.println("\n\n***All Lambda-ed Together:");

        SandwichComponent sandwichComponent = () -> "Bread";

        SandwichComponent vegiDecorator = () -> sandwichComponent.make() + " + Vegi";

        SandwichComponent dressingDecorator = () -> vegiDecorator.make() + " + Dressing";

        SandwichComponent meatDecorator = () -> dressingDecorator.make() + " + Meat";

        SandwichComponent pickleDecorator = () -> meatDecorator.make() + " + pickle";

        SandwichComponent fancyDecorator = () -> pickleDecorator.make() + " + a touch of fancy";

        List<SandwichComponent> SandwichList = new ArrayList<SandwichComponent>() {
            {
                add(sandwichComponent);
                add(vegiDecorator);
                add(dressingDecorator);
                add(meatDecorator);
                add(pickleDecorator);
                add(fancyDecorator);
            }
        };

        SandwichList.forEach(b -> System.out.println(b.make()));
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind to add the code used for SandwichComponent into your question?